# How to display mysql custom column in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have this MySql query:

```
SELECT cityMunicipality, COUNT(cityMunicipality) AS total 
FROM clientinformation 
WHERE cityMunicipality IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY cityMunicipality
```

and this is the result I get:

[image]

How can I display the total in Crystal Reports?

My Crystal Report look like this

[image]

Is there any way to display the `COUNT(cityMunicipality) AS total` column in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

1.: Create with the query a database view and include this in the report.

2.: Include the clientinformation-table in the report and group in the report by the column cityMunicipality.
Than you can use the summarize-functions and use "count" to get the count of the lines in this group.

Disable the details-section and the group-footer. You should only show the group header.

This should solve your problem.